# How to see generated routes in nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Is there a way to see the route list generated by Nuxtjs based on pages folder items ?
The problem is I don't know what exact route name is generated for the component.

```
$router.push({name: 'no-idea-what-the-route-name-is', query: { id: data.id } })
```

this is very useful in a large scale app.
in Laravel easily we can use `php artisan route:list` command in same scenario.

Comment: seems the generated route is kept in ".nuxt/router.js" file !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a generated folder `.nuxt` where you can find `router.js` file with all your routes.

Comment: Theres also a routes.json in that folder.

Comment: note that, .nuxt folder will be generated automatically when executing nuxt dev or nuxt build